# A question on vector norm error analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

${x^*} \in {R^n}$ is the optimal solution of an optimization problem and leads to the minimum objective function ${\left\| {A{x^*} - b} \right\|^2}$, where $A \in {R^{m \times n}}$ and $b \in {R^m}$. But I can only obtain an approximately optimal solution denoted as ${x^*} + \Delta x$ which leads to the objective function ${\left\| {A\left( {{x^*} + \Delta x} \right) - b} \right\|^2}$. Now I can already bound the difference of the two objective functions by ${\Delta \lambda }$:

${\left\| {A\left( {{x^*} + \Delta x} \right) - b} \right\|^2} - {\left\| {A{x^*} - b} \right\|^2} \le \theta \left| {\Delta \lambda } \right|$, where $\theta $ is a constant.

My question is can I bound $\left\| {\Delta x} \right\|$ or $\frac{{{{\left\| {\Delta x} \right\|}^2}}}{{{{\left\| {{x^*}} \right\|}^2}}}$ by some function of ${\Delta \lambda }$, $A$ and $b$, i.e.,
${\left\| {\Delta x} \right\|^2} \le f\left( {\Delta \lambda ,A,b} \right)$ or $\frac{{{{\left\| {\Delta x} \right\|}^2}}}{{{{\left\| {{x^*}} \right\|}^2}}} \le f\left( {\Delta \lambda ,A,b} \right)$.

Or anyone can recommend some relevant materials to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Or can anyone recommend some relevant materials to me? Thanks~

Comment: If $\operatorname{ker} A$ is non-empty, then $\Delta\lambda=0$ for each $\Delta x\in\operatorname{ker} A$, so in this case we cannot bound $\|\Delta x\|$ by a function of $\Delta\lambda$, $A$, and $b$.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky I forget to mention that $A$ is full column rank, which leads to $\rm {ker}~A=0$. Can we bound $\|Δx\|$ in this case? Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll assume that $\|\cdot \|$ is the standard Euclidean norm, that is $\|\ t\|=\sqrt{(t,t)}$ for each $t\in\Bbb R^k$.

Put $\Delta y=A\cdot \Delta x$. If the matrix $A$ has full column rank then $A^+A=I$, where $A^+$ is a [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) of the matrix $A$. Then $\Delta x=A^+\Delta y$, which provides a bound $\|\Delta x\|\le \|A^+\|_2\cdot\|\Delta y\|$, where $\|A^+\|_2$ is the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) of the matrix $A^+$ (see a formula for $\|A\|_2$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases)).

We can bound $\|\Delta y\|$ as follows. Put $c=Ax^*-b$. The value $\|c\|$ is bounded, for instance by $\| b\|$ (see better bounds [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Linear_least-squares)). We have $\|\Delta y\|\le \|c\|+\|\Delta y+c\|$ and $\|c+\Delta y\|^2-\|c\|^2\le \theta \left| {\Delta \lambda } \right|$. It follows $$\|\Delta y\|\le \|c\|+\sqrt{ \|c\|^2+\theta \left| {\Delta \lambda } \right|}.$$

Comment: Many thanks! What I expect is that $\| \Delta x\|$ can be bounded by $|\Delta \lambda|$, and now I know this can be satisfied if $A$ is a square matrix with full rank!

Comment: Could you please see another problem about [the bound of the Euclidean distance between two points on a cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473231/bound-the-euclidean-distance-between-two-points-on-a-cone).